# how to customize windows 7's explorer frame

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

Is there anyone here who knows how to customize the explorer frame in windows 7.
I'm looking for something that could completely change the frame. Not just changing the color. Because that is already included in w7.

**update**
I want to do this because I want to have a unique desktop.
I want to remove this part
[image]

and customize this part, so that it becomes slimmer. Or a bit different:
[image]

Comment: Saying why you want to do this will help answerers.

Comment: Also listing the kinds of changes you **do** want to make would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can completely customize the frames using custom themes. but first you have to apply theme patch to allow you install 3rd party themes. however, if you want to sum all previous steps in one simple installation, you can use skin pack. just google (Skin packs for windows).